# If else not working as expected in PHP--random selection from arrays based on random selection of another array's key.

Tags: php, arrays, random

I'm trying to get a rudimentary PHP name generator working, but I'm hitting a bit of a speedbump here. First, the code:

```
<?php
$gender=array(
    "Male"=>00,
    "Female"=>01,
    );
$m_names=array(
    "Jack"=>00,
    "Bill"=>01,
    "Nathan"=>02,
    );
$f_names=array(
    "Betty"=>00,
    "Margaret"=>01,
    "Rachel"=>02,
    );
if ($gender="Male")
    {
    print_r(array_rand($m_names,1));
    }
else
    {
    print_r(array_rand($f_names,1));
    }
?>
```

The arrays all check out, and I know that print_r(array_rand()); is working fine--I just don't understand what's going on with the if else function.

With the above code, I only get name output from the $m_names array. If I change the if argument to ($gender="Female") I only get $f_names elements. What am I missing here, and how can I think of this concept differently to solve my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean. From what I can see, you have an assignment inside your if statement (and not an equality), which means that you'll always go inside the first part of your `if()` statement (and never in the else part).

Shouldn't you use

```
if ($gender[array_rand($gender)]) {
    // ...
}
```

instead?

What actually happens there is that

```
if ($gender="Male") {
    // ...
}
```

interprets `$gender="Male"`, which affects the value `"Male"` to `$gender`. An affectation returns the value from the affectation. So the statement is evaluated as `"Male"`, which is considered a true value (`true == "Male"`) by the if statement because it actually converts the string into a boolean.

I would also recommend storing simple arrays for your name values. It will make adding new values more easily than using the keys of the `f_names` and `m_names` arrays.

The final result would be as follows:

```
<?php

$gender = array(
    "Male"  => true,
    "Female"=> false,
);

$m_names = array(
    "Jack",
    "Bill",
    "Nathan",
);

$f_names = array(
    "Betty",
    "Margaret",
    "Rachel",
);

if ($gender[array_rand($gender)]) {
    print_r($m_names[array_rand($m_names)]);
} else {
    print_r($f_names[array_rand($f_names)]);
}
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I've only recently started with this stuff, and I'm constantly finding holes in my knowledge. Thanks for helping me fill this one! 

EDIT: I've made the change you suggested, but I'm still only getting $f_names for results when I run it. Any ideas?

Comment: I've made the change you suggested, but I'm still only getting $f_names for results when I run it. I get the opposite effect (male names) when I use if (gender="Female") {} Any ideas?

Comment: You should use `if ($gender === 'Female') {}` or `if ($gender === 'Male') {}`. If you do `$gender = 'whatever string'`, you are actually doing an affectation, and not a comparison, which is why you always go in the first part of your `if` statement.

Comment: You should take a look at the PHP documentation on boolean values. See [http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. I'm not using the equality in the if statement. 

if (gender["Female"]) {}

is what I'm using. Again, I apologize.

Comment: No problem! You should change your array like this:
`$gender = array('Male' => true, 'Female' => false);` :)

Comment: Still not getting anything particularly useful. Would you mind taking a look at what I've posted just below this?

Comment: Hum, is that your complete script? Or do you have something else? What I don't understand here is where you fetch the content from. I think you are actually overcomplicating your script. So let's start from the beginning! :)

Comment: I've edited my answer, so you should have something working now! :)

Comment: Hey, thanks! That's very helpful of you to do. 

If I'm understanding this correctly, this script is now interpreting the arguments within the if statement's functions as meaning the following. 

1. `if ($gender[array_rand($gender)]) {` Operating within $gender, print a random thing from $gender, then do the following 

2. Evaluate $gender for true/false value. If $gender evaluates as "true", print a random element from $m_names.  
3. If $gender evaluates as "false", print a random element from $f_names.

Comment: Exactly. Let's cut this statement into parts. First, you have the `array_rand($gender)`. This statement will fetch a random key from the `$gender` array. Now that you have the key, what you need to fetch is the value from the array. Thus `$gender[array_rand($gender)]`. This will return to you a boolean (`true` or `false`), depending on the random gender which was chosen. And finally, the `if (...) { ... } else { ... }` statement goes in the if part, if the value was evaluated as `true` (male), and in the else part if it was evaluated as `false` (female).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for all your help, I really do appreciate it. I guess I was just missing how to make it evaluate gender for boolean values before. Now I need to figure out how to embed such a thing into a function definition/call. 

Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the question as answered! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten a bit, but now I'm only getting results from the $f_names array--even when I change the boolean in the if statement from true to false. So it now appears that my if is getting skipped and the script is running straight to the else, which calls for results from the $f_names array.

```
<?php
$gender = array(
    "Male: "=>true,
    "Female: "=>false,
    );
$m_names = array(
    "Nathan"=>00,
    );
$f_names = array(
    "Rachel"=>00,
    );
print array_rand($gender);
if ($gender['Male'])
    {
    print_r(array_rand($m_names,1));
     }
else
    {
    print_r(array_rand($f_names,1));
    }
?>
```

I'm getting results like "Male: Nathan" and "Female: Nathan" but never anything to do with the $f_names array, which should be called by the else function when $gender selects as "Female" or  the value of 1.

I'm feeling super dumb, because there's no way this is really that difficult.

Comment: Hum, take a look at the keys in your $gender array. These need to be the same as the key you are using in your if statement. As your key is `"Male :"`, it means that `$gender['Male']` is not the same thing at all.

Comment: You can fix this by using `$gender = array("Male" => true, "Female" => false);`, and then using `if (array_rand($gender)) {`

Comment: I've made exactly those changes, but I'm still getting outputs of "Male: Nathan" and "Female: Nathan". Not sure what's going on here.